# RTC interrupt issue with MSP430F5418

Tags: embedded, msp430, iar, freertos

I am using MSP430F5418 wit IAR EW 5.10.

In my project I am using FreeRTOS 7.0 as operating system.

Consider the scenerio:

1. Setup RTC in alarm mode with one minute interrupt.
2. Create two tasks.
3. When one minute interrupt arrives, send a request to task 2 by task 1.
4. Task 2 response to to task 1 with 4 messages.
5. While receiving messages task 1 calls a simple function which loops for 0x7FFF times.

Here, after the 4th request, an RTC interrupt is generated immediatly even if one minute is not passed.

I am using the Work-around code provided by TI for RTC manipulation.

Can anybody please tell me why this unexpected behaviour happens???

Thank you,

Hari

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in some minimal test code that you can post here (just using the MSP430 peripherals and exclude FreeRTOS)? How does this relate to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517683/rtc-problem-with-msp430)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you have two options

1. Use the newer F5418A which has the RTC problems fixed.
2. Don't use the RTC

I have a project based on the 5418 that was ported from an F149, which does not have a hardware RTC.  As part of the porting process use of the software RTC was replaced with the hardware module.  The TI code was used but there were so many problems with the registers not writing properly that the software RTC was put back in.